# Open mp loop over map of unique pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, unique-ptr, stdmap

I am trying to loop over a map containing unique pointers as values. Here is the implementation. The code compiles, no problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>

class test_class
{
public:
    test_class(int Id, double Td)
    {
        mId = Id;
        mTd = Td;
    }
    void update(double Utd)
    {
        mTd += Utd;
    }
    void print()
    {
        std::cout<<"test_class :: "<<mId<<" Td :: "<<mTd<<std::endl;
    }
private:
    double mTd;
    int mId;
};


typedef std::map< int, std::unique_ptr<test_class> > MapType;
int main() {
    MapType map_u_prt;
    std::vector<int> vec_ids = {1,2,6,5,8,4,3,6,9,2,4,2,5,8,5,7,7,1,4,3,2,7,8,9,9,3,3,5,7,7,9,9,2,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,6};

    int id = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<vec_ids.size(); i++)
    {
        int threadnum = omp_get_thread_num();
        int numthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        id = vec_ids[i];
#pragma omp critical
        std::cout<<"thread :: "<<threadnum<<" , total num thread :: "<<numthreads<<" ---- accessing :: "<<id<<std::endl<<std::flush;
        auto itr = map_u_prt.find(id);
        if(itr == map_u_prt.end())
        {
            map_u_prt[id] = std::make_unique<test_class>(id, 1.0);
        }
        map_u_prt[id]->update(1.0);
    }

    for (const auto& it : map_u_prt)
    {
        std::cout<<"##### "<<std::endl;
        it.second->print();
    }

    std::cout<<"##### SUCCESSFUL ##### "<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I am running the code, I get random seg faults. And I am trying to understanding why is this happening. I kind of see why this is happening (please correct me if I am wrong)  but am not clear on how to solve this issue.

```
auto itr = map_u_prt.find(id);
```

In the above line, the search in the map is not synchronized. That means one thread can see there is an entry for a particular id while another thread has not completed the insertion of pointer and thus the former thread will get a null object and segfaults.

Is there a way to overcome this issue ?. I can put the check and insertion into critical region but in a big loop(a million entries in vec_ids) this is a bottleneck.

Comment: From the reference: `#pragma omp critical [(name)]  {   code_block  }  ` Since your code doesn't contain `{}`, I guess that `code block` is only one line after `#pragma` directive. So, access to the map is not synchronized.

Comment: @AlexF if you are referring to the critical I have in my code ... i put it here only for the print statement in the next line. I wanted to see prints one after the other. This is the only reason for that critical.

Comment: Also if it helps, the posted code is not optimized in anyway. This is meant to be an example.

Comment: This is exactly the point. To make this code run correctly (I don't say faster), map access must be synchronized. You have unsynchronized access (find, update, insert) to the same map from different threads.

Comment: correct ... I see your point. Yes I have tried how you suggested it. As you said its not faster. And it is not helpful for me. So am looking for suggestions on how else can I achieve this.

Comment: Maybe, making `id` a local variable could help. And, second, could you please provide the minimal possible example representing the problem?

Comment: @undermind the code that I posted is the example. It should compile and will cause the problem I mentioned.

Comment: I suggest you to ask another question. Not all algorithms are subject to parallel execution, including this one. Using `omp critical` in this case makes the program slower than non-parallel version. Access to map elements may be parallelized only without insert operations: find + update, providing that different threads don't update the same element.